# How to make virtual enviroment as default interpreter in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, interpreter

I have two environments installed in my pc `Python3.9` and `Conda`. For a project, I needed to create a virtual environment, and I mostly spent my time in that environment. But many times when I create a new file in vscode it selects the `Python3.9` as its interpreter by default, which I don't want. And manually selecting an interpreter by navigating to my venv location is time consuming

[image]

Also when I open notebook in vscode that is `.ipynb` file, it doesn't show my virtual environment as a kernel option and it also doesn't show any option to add any kernel

[image]

So is there any way to make my venv as my default interpreter and avail my venv to notebook as kernal

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `"python.defaultInterpreterPath":"path\to\venv\python.exe"` in **User Settings.json**,
2. Create and open a new folder,
3. Open a new created `.py` file, you will find the interpreter is the one set in User Settings.json.

And every time you open **new project**, it will use this one as interpreter. But existed projects would be like @Steven-MSFT said, it uses the one you selected last time. Please have a try.

Comment: It is saying `duplicate object key` when I am trying to add this setting `"python.defaultInterpreterPath"`  to visual studio code. What should i do?

Comment: @DarkstarDream. It means you've already set this setting, check if its value is the one you want to set as default interpreter. or you may post your User Settings.json

Comment: According to vscode there is no such setting. I also haven't added any settings related to that.

Comment: @DarkstarDream. Is there any possibilities that the error is from your code instead of setting?

Comment: no, i have pasted the same code which you shared and I changed the path with my venv location

Comment: @DarkstarDream. Try to take this command to reset it: `Python:Clear Workspace Interpreter Setting`